# getting error on browser in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

i am beginner in django and i dont know how to solve this problem
i am getting error on browser as:

> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: ^admin/
>
> The current URL, api/Entry/, didn't
>   match any of these.

all my files are:

`mysite/myapp/models.py`:

```
from tastypie.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # For automatic slug generation.
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)[:50]

        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`mysite/myapp/api.py`:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myapp.models import Entry


class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'Entry'
```

`mysite/myapp/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from myapp.api import EntryResource

entry_resource = EntryResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # The normal jazz here...
    (r'^blog/', include('myapp.urls')),
    (r'^api/', include(entry_resource.urls)),
```

`mysite/mysite/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

where my 'mysite' is my project name and 'myapp' is my app
please help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your project-level `urls.py` doesn't include your application-level `urls.py`. Change `mysite/mysite/urls.py` to this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

Also, get rid of `(r'^blog/', include('myapp.urls')),` in `mysite/myapp/urls.py`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: :Thanks for responding but now i am getting error as:

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/entry/?format=json
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls,Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^ ^api/ ^(?P<resource_name>Entry)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
^ ^api/ ^(?P<resource_name>Entry)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
^ ^api/ ^(?P<resource_name>Entry)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
^ ^api/ ^(?P<resource_name>Entry)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
^admin/
The current URL, api/entry/, didn't match any of these.